# how to make RequiredFieldValidator control two validate two control

Tags: asp.net

```
    Are you required applicant?
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="No" />
```

Actually this is code, i do not know why they use two Checkbox instead of Checkboxlist, but they told me do not change it. and make the two checkbox required(using RequiredFieldValidator).
I know how to use RequiredFieldValidator, but how can i make RequiredFieldValidator control two Checkbox, only pass if one of them selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required Field Validator only works on one control at a time -- you'll want to use Custom Validator, or just write your own client/server validation independent of the ASP.NET validators.

See also:

[How do I make a checkbox required on an ASP.NET form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228112/how-do-i-make-a-checkbox-required-on-an-asp-net-form)

[javascript for two checkboxes in aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229876/javascript-for-two-checkboxes-in-aspx)